# Zend_Mail not working in my account

Tags: email, zend-framework

I have got php application written using zend framework

I have action which is supposed to send some emails , I have put the following code inside the action

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is an example message body');
$mail->setFrom('chris@example.com', 'Chris Hope');
$mail->addTo('john@example.com', 'John Smith');
$mail->setSubject('This is an example subject');
$mail->send();
```

This action is run without getting the error but I never receive the email

But when I comment out the above code and use php mail() , it sends the emmail and I am receiving the email also.

Please advise me how to set it up, I have hostgator account

Answer (score 2):

This is my standard setup for Google account, 
so maybe you need to set that config thing for your email provider.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyHtml('.. body ...');
$mail->setFrom('from@email.com');
$mail->addTo('to@email.com');
$mail->setSubject('... subject ...');

// Config
$config = array(
    'auth'      => 'login',
    'username'  => 'username@gmail.com',
    'password'  => 'your-password',
    'port'      => '587',
    'ssl'       => 'tls'
);

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);

// Send email
$mail->send();
```